# Does AutoMapper support ReadOnlyCollections?

Tags: automapper, readonly-collection

I have tried various configurations, but cannot get it working. I am wondering if it is supported?

Comment: As the source or destination member type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the answer is no!